# MATLAB 3D matrix save to TIFFs (2D)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, raster

In Matlab I have a 3D matrix (AxBxT), A by B data in a grid over a period of time T.

I would like to create a number of T, 2D arrays, or TIFF files (rasters) of AxB and save them using a loop with a different name.

what I done:

```
load matrix.mat
for i=1:T
  tiff = matrix(:, :, i);
  outputFileName = sprintf('smb%d.tiff', i);
  imwrite(tiff,outputFileName,'WriteMode', 'append')
end
```

but I cant make it work,

any idea/help is more than welcome

Comment: Does the code runs but not working write? Where does the code fail?

Comment: Have you tried using the `imwrite` function with only the first two parameters?

Comment: how come it is not working? You get an error?

Comment: Yes I have tried. the Problem is that the matrix file is 300x400x700 single. So the error is "Cannot write single image data to a TIFF file with IMWRITE. Use Tiff instead". If the matrix is "matrix= rand(50,50,700) , double; then is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is convert the matrix to a double format then, using double().  This should work:

```
load matrix.mat
matrix = double(matrix);
for i=1:T
  tiff = matrix(:, :, i);
  outputFileName = sprintf('smb%d.tiff', i);
  imwrite(tiff,outputFileName,'WriteMode', 'append')
end
```